# Help converting input string into Unicode integers in Java

Tags: java

I've been set an assignment which requires me to capture the input of 5 strings, convert them to uppercase, output them as a string, convert them to their Unicode integers (using the getNumericValue method) and then manipulate the integers using some basic operators.

I get the first part but I am having trouble with the following:

1. Using the getNumericValue to convert
   my single character literal strings
   into their Unicode integer
   counterparts.
2. Being able to assign these ints to
   variables so I can further process s
   them with operators, all the
   examples I have seen have been
   simple printing out the number and
   not assigning it to a variable,
   since I am a Java noob the syntax is
   still a little confusing for me.

My code is [here](http://pastebin.com/f42ca434a)

If there is a cleaner way of doing what I want please suggest so but without the use of arrays or loops.

Comment: Why not speak to your professor or TA about the difficulty you're having?

Comment: @ Zed - The link is working for me.
@ JF - Our Professor is reluctant to point us toward the solution for some bizarre unknown reason, my TA is also useless and I've asked to be transfered to a different group.

Comment: The link is not working. "Unknown post id, it may have expired or been deleted"

Comment: We're a few months further. The *Community* poked this topic up because it's not marked answered. I am still curious to know the final answer, because it doesn't make any sense to do this without arrays and loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you don't want to do this without arrays or loops.

You can get the unicode values (as ints) making up the string via [String.codePointAt()](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt%28int%29), or get the characters via [charAt()](http://www.j2ee.me/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) followed by a [getNumericValue()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue%28char%29) for each character. But regardless, you're going to *have* to iterate over the set of characters in the string via a loop, or perhaps recursion.

Comment: Well, no... one could do it by recurring on the "first" char and the "rest" of the chars, if one doesn't mind blowing the stack. :)

Comment: The reason I can't use loops or arrays is simply because it hasn't been covered on my course and I would be penalised as a result.

I ended up using CharAt() followed by getNumericValue() which worked perfectly. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Loops are *so* fundamental that I can't believe you'd be penalised for using them - unless he wants you to use Jonathan's suggestion of recursion

Comment: @Unknown - I cannot imagine a TA marking you down for using a language construct or technique that you haven't yet been taught ... UNLESS the question explicitly stated that you shouldn't.  Marking someone down for demonstrating that they are ahead of the class would be totally counter-productive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sounds like op needs to continue researching avenues of learning.

```
// difficult to code without interfering with 
// instructor's prerogative

char ( array ) = String.getchars();

// Now what, unroll the loop?

...
```

As noted by Brian, loops are fundamental. I cannot imagine getChars being assigned before simple array techniques.